# Laravel converting RestApi to GraphQl query

Tags: php, laravel, graphql

As we know, we can define every `RestApi` in `Laravel` and we can implementing them into `Route` or `Controller`s, this below code is one of my simple `RestApi` which i want to convert that to `GraphQl`

```php
public function loginAccount(RequestLoginAccount $request): JsonResponse
{
    $user = User::where('mobile_number', $request->input('mobile_number'))->first();
    if (!$user) {
        return response()->json(['response' => false]);
    }
    try {
        $user->notify(new LoginVerifyCode($user->mobile_number));
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        return response()->json(['response' => -1]);
    }
    return response()->json(['response' => true]);
}
```

after creating simple `resolver` i have this `query`:

command:

```sh
php artisan lighthouse:query loginAccount
```

`loginAccount` query:

```
type Query {
    ///

    loginAccount(mobile_number:String!, verify_code: String!): User
}
```

`loginAccount` resolver:

```php
class LoginAccount
{
    public function __invoke($_, array $args)
    {
        $user = User::where('mobile_number', $args['mobile_number'])->first();
        if (!$user) {
            return null;
        }

        /*try {
            $user->notify(new LoginVerifyCode($user->mobile_number));
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            return response()->json(['response' => -1]);
        }

        return response()->json(['response' => true]);*/
    }
}
```

now could you help me to know whats equivalent of this `RestApi` in `GraphQl`? or is any custom response to define them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how can i convert it from `RestApi` to `GraphQl` and it's resolved

i should be have custom `type` in `schema`:

```
type LoginResponce{
    response:Int
}
```

custom `GraphQl` resolve should be has:

```php
class LoginAccount
{
    public function __invoke($_, array $args): array
    {
        $user = User::where('mobile_number', $args['mobile_number'])->first();
        if (!$user) {
            return ['response' => -1];
        }

        try {
            $user->notify(new LoginVerifyCode($user->mobile_number));
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            return ['response' => -2];
        }

        return ['response' => 1];
    }
}
```

and `query`:

```
type Query {
    //
    loginAccount(mobile_number:String!): LoginResponce
}
```

`GraphQl` query:

```
query {
  loginAccount(mobile_number: "00000") {
    response
  }
}
```